# SQL Query: Retrieve click data from journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, sql

I am looking for help writing an SQL query to find the data for who clicked on an email in a journey. I already know I can export the subscriber ID and a few other items from the tracking extract but I am looking to export all the information within the data extension (ie. Name, Address, DOB, ZIP, etc...).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to join the [_Click Dataview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5) to the DE that has the information you want to include

[SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) from W3 School

a basic example would be

```
Select a.name, b.click
from [DENAME] a
join _click b on b.subscriberkey = a.subscriberkey
where b.jobid = XXX
```

You can then also join the [_Journey dataviews](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_journey.htm&type=5) if you want to add where clauses to pull data from a single journey

Answer (score 0):

Journey Builder sends are triggered sends. You can utilize the TriggeredSendCustomerKey with the Click Data View to query clicks from a Journey Email Send. You can then join on your data extension to add desired DE fields (Name, Address, DOB, ZIP, etc...) to your query results.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5